# Unconfirmed transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made a transfer over 24hr ago and it's yet to be confirmed. Pls help. The link is https://blockchain.info/tx/35dd84368ffc04c49980f7816b667efb84dbfd974070d429edaadacb9cf13f13. 
Thanks

Comment: Should take more time to confirm. Lookup your tx on https://www.blockonomics.co to get suggestions on what to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you included fees of about 35 sat/B on your transaction.

Take a look at the [table on this page](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/), and you can see with that fee, many transactions with that fee take a VERY long time to be confirmed (nearly infinite).

You can not expect a transaction to be confirmed in 24 hours at that fee.  It may take over a week, or it may never get confirmed.

The recommended fee is currently around 420 sat/B, or more than 10x what you paid.

Comment: I was told that if it doesn't get confirmed after sometime, the transaction is reversed. Is there anyway to reverse it and increase the transaction fee?